# Last 3 months Sales rolling SQl, MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns region, order date and sales order by region and then order date (SQL, MYSQL). I want to calculate rolling last 3 months sum of sales for a particular region. Is there any way to do it? Please find below the Sample Output

[image]

Comment: There is not just "any way to do it".  There are multiple different ways.  Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you are asking about -- and what the best method is.

Comment: Thanks for Replying @GordonLinoff. Please find below the desired output

Region Date Sales L3M Sales
East 1/22/2019        31     Null
East 2/22/2019        79 Null
East 3/22/2019        54 164
East 4/22/2019         98 231
East 5/22/2019         86 238
East 6/22/2019         58 242
East 7/22/2019         70 214
West 1/22/2019 81 Null
West 2/22/2019 53 Null
West 3/22/2019 39 173
West 4/22/2019 58 150
West 5/22/2019 47 144
West 6/22/2019 41 146
West 7/22/2019 52 140

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your sample desired results. In the comment they are hard to read.

Comment: @O.Jones . Updated the question based on your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help, i found an answer to the question

SELECT
Region, Date, Sales,
lag(Sales,0) OVER (
PARTITION BY Region
ORDER BY Date ) + lag(Sales,1) OVER (
PARTITION BY Region
ORDER BY Date ) + lag(Sales,2) OVER (
PARTITION BY Region
ORDER BY Date ) L3M_Sales
FROM
Table;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT region, LAST_DAY(orderdate) month_ending, SUM(sales)
  FROM tbl
 WHERE orderdate >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
 GROUP BY region, LAST_DAY(orderdate)
```

This uses MySQL's `LAST_DAY()` function to grab the end of the month for each sale, then filters the table contents to pick out sales starting with the beginning of the month three months ago.

The expression `LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH` computes to

```
LAST_DAY(2021-02-17T09:50) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
2021-02-28 + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
2021-03-01 - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
2020-12-01
```

Therefore, you'll get December, January, and incomplete February sales here when you run this query in February.

Comment: Thanks for Replying @O.jones. But this will find last 3 months sum from today's date is suppose. Please find below the desired output

Region Date Sales L3M Sales
East 1/22/2019        31     Null
East 2/22/2019        79 Null
East 3/22/2019        54 164
East 4/22/2019         98 231
East 5/22/2019         86 238
East 6/22/2019         58 242
East 7/22/2019         70 214
West 1/22/2019 81 Null
West 2/22/2019 53 Null
West 3/22/2019 39 173
West 4/22/2019 58 150
West 5/22/2019 47 144
West 6/22/2019 41 146

Thanks,
Aniket